How to remove the vertical white side-line created by clangd with lazy.nvim?
this thick white and blue line is distracting me like crazy and it appears to be of no use. It appeared when I first installed clangd with mason.nvim.
I'm using nvim-cmp. I have no idea what configuration option to look for because I have no idea what this line is called; any help would be appreciated


Is this column a signcolumn? What happens if you set it to no:
:set signcolumn=no?

That's it! It was exactly a signcolumn and set signcolumn=no removes it. Thanks!

I wrote it as an answer, so it will be more visible to other people.

This one is called signcolumn. You can disable it with this command:
:set signcolumn=no

To read more about signcolumn: :h signcolumn.
There are a couple of options for signcolumn one of them is number it allows to merge line number with indications from signcolumn so you won't miss information from clangd.
